# what is a search query in google custom search engine?

Tags: python, google-api, google-custom-search

This question has nothing to do with technical help, however i need to understand what is a search query under google custom search api. If I am not mistaken, a search query is what i query in google search box isn't it ?.

If so, under google custom search api, it was said, that i can make 100 queries a day. Keeping that in mind, i was being cautious in making queries and the total queries were 54.

After 54 queries, i received the below error. The error says `This API requires billing to be enabled on the project. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/billing?project=236852110619 to enable billing`. Why is it so ?

[image]

[image]

**Does that mean after billing, can i utilize 46 queries that belong to free quota ?**

Answer (score 0):

Quota for this API seems to be pro-rated if you start in the middle of a day. Are you able to get the full 100 queries the next day?